# Make a web page inaccessible for users

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a web application(J2EE+apache+struts2+jsp+jqgrid) and some JSPs(in /webcontent/data_provider folder) that jQGrid uses them to fetch data from mysql DB and fill the grid with, but I don't want users to access those JSPs.
What can I do?
Thanks in advance buddies.

Answer (score 5):

put those JSP into `WEB-INF` or create a filter that particular URL gets hit and check if user is authenticated to access it allow, restrict otherwise

Comment: But jQGrid accesses them. He just wants to hide it from users.